# is there a way to change the Legend of graph in emmeans?

Tags: r, emmeans

I need to change the order in the Legend of a graph made by emmeans using emmip, but I can't find anything online abput it.

That's the code I use:

```
emmip(anovaSameTaskErr, TaskSw ~ SubjectSw ~ CueDuration)
```

The three variables have 2 levels, CueDuration is the X and interactions between the two other are the lines on the graph.
The interactions present on a specific order in the Legend and I need them to be in another order.

Answer (score 0):

`emmeans::emmip` just returns a standard `ggplot` object, which can be manipulated extensively.

Here's a simple example from the help page for the function:

```
fit <- lm(noise ~ size * type * side, data = auto.noise)
emmip(fit, type ~ size | side)
```

To change the order of the legend, you specify the levels in `scale_*_discrete`.

```
emmip(fit, type ~ size | side) +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("Octel", "Std"))
```

[image]