# Change Legend Labels and Order in emmip plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, emmeans

I have a plot using emmip and I have been successful of modifying the labels of the panels and the x axis label but I have been unsuccessful changing the labels and the order of the legend, any suggestions?

It should be Phonemes by Cognate Status

and the label /k/ - Cognate, /k/ Noncognate, ....

This is the code for this plot.

[image]

```
###{r HS in CS interaction plot with pre switch syllable count vs phoneme }
(mylist <- list(
    Syl_Pre_Switch = seq(7,12,by=1),
    phoneTxtGrid=c("p","t","k"), 
    CogStatus=c("Cog", "Cag")))

emmip(modelHSCSwithDistance, phonemeTxtGrid*CogStatus ~ Syl_Pre_Switch,
      at=mylist, CIs = TRUE) +  
    ggplot2::facet_grid(~factor(phonemeTxtGrid, 
                        levels=c('p', 't', 'k'))) + 
        xlab("Syllables After Cognate") + 
        labs(fill = "Stops by Cognate Status")
```

I tried this suggestion from this post [is there a way to change the Legend of graph in emmeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586983/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-legend-of-graph-in-emmeans)

Adding

```
 scale_color_discrete()
```

but I have been unsuccessful in changing the label name.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edited the code in the OP so it can be read. May I suggest that the spacebar and return key can be your friends?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to modify the plot, e.g., by adding more **ggplot2** calls to it. But I think you are better off starting (almost) over. Start with:

```
plot.data <- emmip(<your emmip arguments>, plotit = FALSE)
```

This gives you a data frame with everything that goes into the plot (see `? emmip` for details on naming). You can then rearrange this data frame, add columns, etc., then plot what you want using those data, using `ggplot()` or whatever else you may prefer.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do it like this:

```
    (mylist222 <- list(Sylb_PostCog=seq(2,5,by = 1),phoneTxtGrid=c("p","t","k"), CogStatus=c("Cog", "Cag")))
emmip(modelHSvsL2CSwithDistancePostCogToSwitch, phonemeTxtGrid*CogStatus*SpeakGroup ~ Sylb_PostCog, at=mylist222, CIs = TRUE)  + ggplot2::facet_grid(SpeakGroup~factor(phonemeTxtGrid, levels = c("p", "t", "k"))) + labs(x = "Syllables Post Cognate", colour = "Stops by Cognate Status and Speaker Group") +  scale_color_hue(labels = c("/k/ Cognate HS", "/p/ Cognate HS", "/t/ Cognate HS", "/k/ Noncognate HS", "/p/ Noncognate HS", "/t/ Noncognate HS", "/k/ Cognate L2", "/p/ Cognate L2", "/t/ Cognate L2", "/k/ Noncognate L2", "/p/ Noncognate L2", "/t/ Noncognate L2"))
```

Comment: This is not readable. Please edit it and add line breaks. I've already cleaned up your code once before, now it's your turn.